# Unity Native Android application Android Studio Build Failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have exported a unity Library file for android and I created an android studio I want to import the the unityLibrary project.

Sharing the code
Inside the Settings.gradle

```
include (":unityLibrary")
project(":unityLibrary").projectDir= File("C:\\ProjectLearning\\AndroidProjects\\NativeAndroidUnityIntegration\\unityLibrary")
```

Inside build.gradle file

```
implementation (project(":unityLibrary"))
implementation(fileTree(mapOf(project((":unityLibrary").toString()) to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
```

### I am getting the below error:
1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\ProjectLearning\AndroidProjects\NativeAndroidUnityIntegration\app\build.gradle.kts' line: 50
- What went wrong:
  Could not set unknown property 'DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':unityLibrary'', configuration='default'}' for directory 'null' of type org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileTree.

I want to take the build and run the application in NativeAndroid Application.